# Where can I declare my trigger for NSMenu?

Tags: swift, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I manually created an NSMenu in my AppDelegate like so:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSMenuDelegate {


  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        
    rightClickMenu = RightClickMenu.createMenu();

  }
```

And I want to keep all triggers for my NSMenu in a separate Class like that:

```swift
class RightClickMenu {
    static func createMenu() -> NSMenu {
        let menu = NSMenu(title: "Status Bar Menu")
         menu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Test",
            action: #selector(RightClickMenu.test(_:)),
            keyEquivalent: "")

        return menu

    }
    
    //This func never gets triggered and menu item is grey
    @objc func test(_ sender: Any?){
        print("Test")
    }
    
}
```

I think it has something to do with the location where the function is declared. At least I know that it works in the AppDelegate but why does it not work here? Couldn't find a good source to explain this Lifecycle at all...

I am coming from a SwiftUI Background only and I am a newbie in Swift and it is a little challenging to learn all this old tech it is based on. Hope you can help me.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Actions assigned to NSMenuItem dont seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816255/actions-assigned-to-nsmenuitem-dont-seem-to-work)

Comment: I will try it out thanks

Comment: Sadly it didn't change anything...

Comment: Which object is the target of the menu items?

Comment: @Willeke got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to this was to use an Storyboard NSMenu from the SwiftUI default Project with an AppDelegate. This works perfect, so I recommend this as an solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
let eventHud = RightClickMenu()

class RightClickMenu {

    static func createMenu() -> NSMenu {
        let menu = NSMenu(title: "Status Bar Menu")
        let item = NSMenuItem(title: "Test", action:  #selector(RightClickMenu.test(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
        item.target = eventHud
        menu.addItem(item)
        return menu
    }
    
    
    @objc func test(_ sender: Any?){
        print("Test")
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expressing the method in the selector as a static function (by referencing it on the class).  Change it to

`action: #selector(test(_:))`

Answer (score 0):

As `RightClickMenu` is just sth boilerplate,

better to modify it as

```
extension NSMenu{

    static func createMenu() -> NSMenu {
        let menu = NSMenu(title: "Status Bar Menu")
        let item = NSMenuItem(title: "Test", action:  #selector(NSMenu.test(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
        item.target = menu
        menu.addItem(item)
        return menu
    }
    
   
    @objc func test(_ sender: Any?){
        print("Test")
    }
    
}
```